# Spyder flashes in cmd and closes

Tags: spyder

This is always an issue. I did a refresh installed, deleted the lock folder and still spyder will not launch.  I am running version 3.3.2 on windows.

Comment: Try running it from the command line

Comment: yes i do that and it just give me a new command prompt, not even a flash

Comment: No output? What about a log file? As it stands, your problem is very difficult to diagnose due to lack of any concrete information.

Comment: how do i get a log file?

Comment: it seems I have both a spyder.exe and a spyder3.exe in my Anaconda3/Scripts folder could that have anything to do with it?  When i try to run spyder3.exe I get a window saying 'unable to create process'.  Also my spyder-script.py is blank.  why does it install with blank spyder-script?

Comment: well downgrading to spyder 3.3.1 worked.  that's annoying, maybe i can create bug report that when downloading 3.3.2 the spyder-script.py is empty?

Comment: First you have to make sure that that isn't somehow your fault, but yes, you should definitely consider filing a bug report if you can prove that it isn't.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It seems you installed 3.3.2 with pip instead of using conda, If that was the case, please don't fill a bug report about it because we explicitly [warn](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases/tag/v3.3.2) against it.

Comment: i used conda.  i can try it again and update spyder with conda and see what the results are.

Comment: I just tried updating again to 3.3.2 and the spyder-script.py file is blank.  I am running windows 10.  When i reverted to 3.3.1 the script has the system code and spyder runs.  I don't see the script when downloading the source code [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases) for 3.3.2